# Separate handwritten scanned images

Tags: python, image-processing, nlp, tesseract

I have bunch of scanned pdf forms, few of them have few handwritten content also. I want to separate pages having handwritten content from others not having hand written content using python.

Please suggest?

Comment: please do your own research. your post is too broad. please read [ask]

Comment: May be..........

Comment: from the guidelines: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

You could provide a lot more information. Example images, provide any own attempts or research findings. Usually you won't get solutions for such general and broad problems. I mean we do not even know how handwriting looks where you are from, how could we advise on doing any image-processing on it? are there any constaints? color, thickness... is all non-handwritten text ORC readable? we cannot cover all of that

Comment: Ok got it.........